# What does ".managed" mean in a babushka package name?

Tags: package-management

I did a search for java with babushka, and got the following results:

```
Name                 | Source                                               | Runs    |  ✓ | Command
---------------------+------------------------------------------------------+---------+------+--------------------------------------------
java.managed         | git://github.com/all4miller/babushka-deps.git        | 1 ever  | 100% | babushka all4miller:java.managed
java.managed         | git://github.com/benhoskings/babushka-deps.git       | 2 ever  | 50%  | babushka benhoskings:java.managed
java environment     | git://github.com/compactcode/babushka-deps.git       | 4 ever  | 75%  | babushka compactcode:'java environment'
java dev environment | git://github.com/compactcode/babushka-deps.git       | 21 ever | 14%  | babushka compactcode:'java dev environment'
java.environment     | git://github.com/compactcode/babushka-deps.git       | 1 ever  | 100% | babushka compactcode:java.environment
java.managed         | git://github.com/compactcode/babushka-deps.git       | 1 ever  | 0%   | babushka compactcode:java.managed
java                 | git://github.com/cheef/babushka-deps.git             | 1 ever  | 100% | babushka cheef:java
java                 | http://chris-berkhouts-macbook-pro-2.local:9292/.git | 4 ever  | 25%  | ✣
java-6-sun           | https://github.com/cheef/babushka-deps.git           | 2 ever  | 0%   | babushka cheef:java-6-sun
```

"java.managed" looks the most promising, because I trust benhoskings more than the others. But what does the ".managed" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just his convention for indicating the template type the dep was based on.
`managed` means that dependency was defined with the `managed` template.

From http://ben.hoskings.net/2010-08-01-design-and-dsl-changes-in-babushka-v0.6 (emphasis mine):

> That's all cleaned up now. Just as sources have been unified, deps are always defined with the dep top-level method now, whether they use a template or not. Instead of saying gem 'hpricot', you say either dep 'hpricot', :template => 'gem', or dep 'hpricot.gem'. These two styles produce the same dep---**the choice is there to allow you to include the template type in the dep's name**.

Earlier in the same article, he explains that the original name for the `managed` template was `pkg`, which was causing confusion for his Mac users who assumed it meant 
they were for Mac installer packages:

> The pkg template was renamed to managed because it looked like it handled OS X installer packages.

Unfortunately, that leads to confusion in the dep list: I'm guessing you wouldn't have asked what the package suffix name meant if it was called "java.pkg". :-)